# Error 404 - HTML page not rendering for other apps than main application

Tags: django, django-templates, http-status-code-404

So I've created several apps in my Django project and I have one main app called main_app.

The other apps are called profile_app, settings_app, messages_app.

**The issue**:

The issues that I have is that whenever I try to run a certain view function from e.g profile_app in main_app using the app namespace and URL name (e.g profilepage_app:"profile-redirect"), I receive a 404 error stating "Page not found".

**I have done the following**:

- Registret all apps.
- Linked the urls.py file in my settings URL.
- Tried to create a test view function inside the main_app and it works perfectly, but the same function does not work in the profile_app.
- Created another test app in order to see if I still have the same issue (I did).

So the problem is that whatever link from all apps (except main_app) that I try to display in the browser generats the "Page not found"-error.

**My questions**:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I resolve this issue?
3. Has this something to do with my settings file?

**The error**:

**My view**:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import View

from profile_app.forms import *
from profile_app.models import *
from messages_app.models import Message

user = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
# Create your views here.

## Redirect to user profile from the navbar

class ProfilePageView(View):
    model = ProfilepageMember
    template_name = "profile_app/profilepage.html"
    
    def get(self, request, user_name):
        user_related_data = ProfilepageMember.objects.filter(member__username = user_name)
        context = {"user_related_data": user_related_data}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

**My URLS**:

```
"""
URL configuration for bodyswap_project project.

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("auth_app.urls")),
    path("", include("main_app.urls")),
    path("", include("profile_app.urls")),
    path("", include("messages_app.urls")),
    path("", include("settings_app.urls")),
]
```

**Settings**:

```
"""
"""
Django settings for body project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.getenv("DEBUG")

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# HTTPS settings

# Set this to True in production to avoid transmitting the CSRF cookie over HTTP accidentally.
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
# Set this to True in production to avoid transmitting the CSRF cookie over HTTP accidentally.
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
# Change to True in production
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False

# HSTS settings

# SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 31536000  # 1 year
# SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = False

# Email settings for the contact form
# Used only during development

EMAIL_HOST = os.getenv("EMAIL_HOST")
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")
EMAIL_PORT = os.getenv("EMAIL_PORT")

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Installed apps
    'main_app.apps.MainAppConfig',
    'auth_app.apps.AuthAppConfig',
    'profile_app.apps.ProfileAppConfig',
    'settings_app.apps.SettingsAppConfig',
    'messages_app.apps.MessagesAppConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'body.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'body.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static"
]


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
# This is set when creating a custom user model.
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main_app.Member'
```

I appreciate all help.

Comment: Share the `bodyswap_project.urls`.

Comment: Hello! I've now uploaded the URLs. Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

You included the `profilepage/urls.py` module in the URLs, but likely *after* you included the `static` paths somewhere.

> How can I resolve this issue?

You normally define the static and media paths at the *root* `urls.py` *after* all other paths, such that it is only used if the matches of all other paths fail, so:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = (
    [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', include('auth_app.urls')),      # 🖘 no static/media urls
        path('', include('main_app.urls')),      # 🖘 no static/media urls
        path('', include('profile_app.urls')),   # 🖘 no static/media urls
        path('', include('messages_app.urls')),  # 🖘 no static/media urls
        path('', include('settings_app.urls')),  # 🖘 no static/media URLs
    ]
    + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
)
```

It is thus important that the `auth_app.urls`, `main_app.urls`, `profile_app.urls`, `messages_app.urls` and `settings_app.urls` do *not* contains the static/media paths. Strictly speaking that is not a problem either, as long as these are not "wildcards" that will match any path, but as you found out, that is easily the case.

> Has this something to do with my settings file?

**No**: The order of the URLs is important: Django will match these top to bottom, and the first pattern that matches will "fire". If you thus have a path pattern that matches *any* path, it will always fire, and Django will thus never look to any paths further in the chain.

Subclassing the `View` class directly is often *not* necessary. In this case your view looks like a [**`DetailView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView). By using a `DetailView` instead of a simple `View`, you often do not have to implement a lot of boilerplate code.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import DetailView


class ProfilePageView(DetailView):
    model = ProfilepageMember
    template_name = 'profile_app/profilepage.html'
    context_object_name = 'user_related_data'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return get_object_or_404(ProfilepageMember, member__username=user_name)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I've done some changes to my codes and it work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

So what I did wrong is that the first parameter in the URLs are empty. They cannot be empty.

````
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("autentisering/", include("auth_app.urls")),
    path("hem/", include("main_app.urls")),
    path("profil/", include("profile_app.urls")),
    path("meddelanden/", include("messages_app.urls")),
    path("inställningar/", include("settings_app.urls")),
]

```
````

Comment: They can, as long as there is not a path included in one of these. Where did you define the `STATIC` URLs?